# Dropdown menu causing text to look ugly on bootstrap navbar

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to know why my text on Bootstrap's navbar turns very thin when ever I click on a dropdown menu inside the navbar, then goes back to normal after i close the menu (click elsewhere). If you click on Stackoverflow's message box on the top navbar of this site, you will notice that the text stays the same, that's what I'm looking to do in my site. I've seen many sites that have this issue so I know it's nothing new but I can't figure it out or have tried searching but couldn't find anything that could help me.

This is a good example of a site that has the same problem I have:
https://bootsnipp.com

Notice that when you click on any submenu how all the text on that bar turns very thin. It only happens on dropdown menus, if you click on the search bar it stays the same.

Comment: Here's a random site I searched on Google that does the same, except on this one it looks like just hovering the dropdown menu it gives that same ugly effect:
http://www.supremem.com/new_2017/smartmenus-1.0.1/demo/bootstrap-navbar-fixed-top.html#

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please include the relevant code from your website in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that we can see your specific issue and help.